# How do you build an Electron.Net app for ubuntu platform?

Tags: ubuntu, electron.net

I am trying to build a project with Electron.Net for Ubuntu 20.04 (64 bit).

I can build the same project fine for windows with "electronize build /target win"

I have tried "electronize build /target custom ubuntu.20.04-x64;ubuntu /electron-arch x64"

I have also tried to build with " electron-builder" but cannot find a good example for package.json for ubuntu.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux).
Follow this guide https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/windows/wsl/install-win10 to install WSL and after install dotnet, nodeJS and electron.net in your linux subsystem.
Open your project path in linux terminal, write `export PATH="$HOME/.dotnet/tools:$PATH"` and build it (/target linux).